# How to show a message before redirecting to an other page?

Tags: html, codeigniter, echo

I have an example page to reset password. If this user submits this form , it will show a message like "your password successfully update" and redirect to an other page. What’s wrong about my script ?

```
public function updatepassword(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword','Current Password',
        'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword','Current Password',
        'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            $password1 = $this->input->post('newpassword');
            $password2 = $this->input->post('confpassword');
            $this->load->model('app_model');

            $id = $this->session->flashdata('item');;
            // die(var_dump($id));
            if($password1 == $password2){
                if($this->app_model->update_password($password1, $id)){
                    $this->db->where('email', $id);
                    $this->db->update('login', array('token' => random_string('alnum',20)));

                     echo 'Password Sukses Diperbaharui'and redirect('web');//here

                }else{
                    echo 'Password Gagal Diperbaharui';
                }

            }else{
                echo 'Password is not matching';

            }


        }else{
            echo validation_errors();
        }

}
```

Comment: `code` <script type="text/javascript">
alert("YOUR MESSAGE HERE");
location="REDIRECTION_PAGE.php";
</script>

Comment: we need to add 'echo' before <script type > ?

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("YOUR MESSAGE HERE"); location="REDIRECTION_PAGE.php"; </script>';

Comment: Message: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: echo <"script type='text/javascript'"> alert("YOUR MESSAGE HERE"); "location='web'"; <"/script">  llike this ?

Comment: `echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Record Updated  Successfully');
window.location.href='dh_gl_sub_cat.php';
</SCRIPT>");`

Comment: You  need to learn the basics of PHP syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> window.alert('Record Updated Successfully'); window.location.href='dh_gl_sub_cat.php'; </SCRIPT>");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of feasible ways is that using javascript to do redirection.

Add scripts to the success page and set the timeout.

```
<?php
public function updatepassword() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword','Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword','Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $password1 = $this->input->post('newpassword');
        $password2 = $this->input->post('confpassword');
        $this->load->model('app_model');

        $id = $this->session->flashdata('item');;
        // die(var_dump($id));
        if ($password1 == $password2) {

            if ($this->app_model->update_password($password1, $id)) {

                $this->db->where('email', $id);
                $this->db->update('login', array('token' => random_string('alnum',20)));

                // add below codes
                ?>
                Password Sukses Diperbaharui
                <script>
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        document.location.href = 'web';
                    }, 3000);
                </script>
                <?php
                // add above codes

            } else {
                echo 'Password Gagal Diperbaharui';
            }

        } else {
            echo 'Password is not matching';
        }

    } else {
        echo validation_errors();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: its have a error sir ..  Message: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting T_FUNCTION

Comment: Remove the `<?php` at the beginning and `?>` at the end. I marked which part of codes you need to use.

Comment: didnt work sir , not showing "Password Sukses Diperbaharui"